# unable to use installed types with typescript in svelte

Tags: typescript, svelte

I've had a hard time being able to get my project to compile with an installed type. I'm using MediaRecorder, and I've installed @types/dom-mediacapture-record. With the default set up I was unable to get MediaRecorder recognized.

I've managed to get things working by 1) not extending  @tsconfig/svelte/tsconfig.json and 2) add the specific type along with "svelte" under types: "types": ["sevlte", "@types/dom-mediacapture-record"]. I wasn't able to get this to work using `typeRoots`

I couldn't find examples of anyone else having this trouble online, so I feel like I must be missing something obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I've quickly tried and seemed to work (doesn't need any changes to `tsconfig.json`):

### Edit

I found out there is a problem with my original code when importing some types from the current project (as opposed to some imported types from `node_modules`) in addition to `dom-mediacapture-record`. Wrapping `interface Window...` in `declare global {...}` solves this. So here goes the updated code:

```
// add a file "<your filename here>.d.ts" to your src directory containing 
// the following code:

// import the types from @types/dom-mediacapture-record in order
// to extend the existing Window type with them
import * as dmr from "dom-mediacapture-record";
import type { MyCustomInterface } from "./customStuff";

// Using TypeScript's declaration merging, "extend" the existing 
// Window interface
declare global {
   interface Window extends dmr, MyCustomInterface {}
}
```

### Version Before Edit:

```
// add a file "<your filename here>.d.ts" to your src directory containing 
// the following code:

// import the types from @types/dom-mediacapture-record in order
// to extend the existing Window type with them
import * as dmr from "dom-mediacapture-record";

// Using TypeScript's declaration merging, "extend" the existing 
// Window interface
interface Window extends dmr {}
```

Comment: This looks good as well! I'm not sure that's its better than adding to the tsconfig though, and I still wonder what it is that I'm missing in terms of the proper svelte approach to installed types. If steps such as yours or mine are necessary, why isn't there documentation of this?

Comment: I think maybe the approach with adding the `d.ts` is a little bit less invasive than stopping to use the base `tsconfig.json` file because that base might change in future svelte updates. In that case it might not be clear any more or forgot why you stopped using the base `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: Great point. I'll let this bake a bit b/c I want to see if there's some standard svelte answer, otherwise I'll mark this as an answer (tried to upvote it, but its hidden b/c I'm new here)

Comment: In talking with the people on the svelte discord, it sounds like our options here are what we need to do, at least for now. Thank you for your help Christian!

Comment: You're welcome, and thanks for confirming with the Svelte discord, that's good to know. And of course for accepting the answer!